# Other Maps API in Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, maps

Can I use other maps api in Phonegap beside Google Maps?
I see [this](http://tomschott.com/articles/phonegap-google-maps-example) tutorial and there's a code

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+ position.coords.latitude +","+ position.coords.longitude +"&amp;zoom=11&amp;size=300x300&amp;sensor=false
```

As far as I can understand, I can just simply change it to other API url right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use any other map api as long as it is capable of running in mobile browsers. If you are using the latest version of Phonegap, just make sure you have [whitelisted](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide) the new api url.